# I'd like to change the value of an <audio> without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, audio

i'm using rails 4 and javascript for a personal web app. Here's the problem:
i'd like to change randomly the value of `<audio>` when i click on `<button>`.
To generate the path of the `<audio>` i use a ruby function that return the value of the sound from the database. What i would like to do is to click on the `<button>` and everytime i click on it the value of the `<audio>` change without reloading the page.
Here's and example:

```
<button> Click me!</button>
<audio><source src="<%= $soundpath %>"></audio>
/* I click on the button and the sound path into src="" should change everytime i click on the button without reloading the page*/
<audio><source src="<%= $soundpath %>" <--[this should be different from the previus one]></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's AJAX functions to request a URL that will respond with the text to set the src to:

In your javascript file:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $.get( "/sounds/next_source", function( data ) {
    $( "audio" ).attr( "src", data );
  });
}
```

Then make sure you have a route set up for this action and then implement it in the controller:

```
def next_source
    @src = Sound.last.url

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :plain => @src }
  end
end
```

Comment: ok sorry, now i'll change my request XD i want to call a that ruby function from the controller into the javascript function like                                function f1(){ if(s==true) /* here's i wanto to call the ruby function from the controller*/    } without reload the page on the click

Comment: My answer doesn't reload the page. It makes an asynchronous request for the new string to set src to. If you want to cause the AJAX request to happen because of an if statement, then change line 1 to your if statement.